# VSCode Dev Container GPG Windows WSL error

Tags: gnupg, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I'm trying to get GPG to work in my dev container (default python container) under Windows WSL2 for signed commits and getting error when trying to reload gpg agent.

Following [official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials#_sharing-gpg-keys):

1. Installed gpg4win on Windows
2. Connected to Dev Container and added `pinentry-program /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Gpg4win/bin/pinentry.exe` to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file

And when I'm trying to reload gpg agent using command `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`
I'm getting:

```
gpg-connect-agent: no running gpg-agent - starting '/usr/bin/gpg-agent'
gpg-connect-agent: failed to create temporary file '/root/.gnupg/.#lk0x000055a2a31ddd90.aae1d09ea764.617': No such file or directory
gpg-connect-agent: can't connect to the agent: No such file or directory
gpg-connect-agent: error sending standard options: No agent running
```

Tried these solutions and none of them worked:

1. [Integration of GPG-signed Git commits in VSCode Dev Container (WSL2 Ubuntu v20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71155464/integration-of-gpg-signed-git-commits-in-vscode-dev-container-wsl2-ubuntu-v20)
2. https://www.39digits.com/signed-git-commits-on-wsl2-using-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround by just mounting my local `.gnupg` folder to the dev container using devcontainer config file `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`

```
"mounts": [
  "source=${localEnv:USERPROFILE}/.gnupg,target=/home/vscode/.gnupg,type=bind"
],
"remoteUser": "vscode"
```